# Python, database results are saved with ('result')

Tags: python, mysql

I select some urls from my database using a simple code

```
def crearArchivo(self):
        #Se conecta a la base de datos
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","proyectoacademias" )

        cursor = db.cursor()

        #Selecciona la lista de valores que no hayan sido procesados
        sql = "SELECT url_paper_web FROM acw_papers_web WHERE finalizado = 0"

        cursor.execute(sql)

        #Recibe todos los datos
        datos = cursor.fetchall()

        #Crea el archivo
        archivo = open('urls.txt','w')
        archivo.close()

        #Lo abre
        archivo = open('urls.txt','w')

        #Establece un contador para determinar el numero de filas
        contador=0;

        #Para cada fila la guarda en el archivo y si no es la ultima agrega un salto de linea
        for columna in datos:

            contador+=1;

            archivo.write(str(columna))

            if(contador!=len(datos)):
                archivo.write("\n") 


        #Se cierra todo
        archivo.close()
        db.close()
```

This method places those links in a file... the problem is that those links instead of being saved like http:// google.com they are saved like ('http://google.com')

Comment: Tip: Spanish is beautiful, but programming in english makes it easier for you to share your code if you ever need to do so. It's an useful habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `columna` variable is actualy a row, not a single column. Simply select the first value in that row:

```
archivo.write(columna[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because columna is a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html). It looks like you want to write the first (and in this case, the only element):

```
archivo.write(columna[0])
```